# How to use customvision.ai to create object detection model for TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, azure-cognitive-services, tensorflow-lite, microsoft-custom-vision

I have an object detection model that I've created in https://customvision.ai. If I export it as a TensorFlow Lite model, I get a model that expects `FLOAT32 [1, 416, 416, 3]` as input and returns `FLOAT32 [1, 13, 13, 35]` as output (as per TensorFlow Lite's `visualize.py`).

I would like to use that model in an Android app. I've tried to load the `.tflite` model file into the [TensorFlow Lite object detection sample app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/README.md), however it expects a different format. I get the following exception when running the app. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 13, 13, 35] and a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].`

Is it feasible to adapt the sample app to use the model from customvision.ai?

How should I interpret the shape `[1, 13, 13, 35]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to work it out.